# .htaccess not allowing $_POST variables with ErrorDocument 404

Tags: php, ajax, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building a CMS over an MVC framework I'm also building, but I'm stuck here. The full code can be found at [this link to github](https://github.com/ForkLabs/MiniMVC).

Ok, the problem I'm having is with this .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST [NC]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

When I run the code on "auth/login" via this ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "auth/login",
  dataType: "json",
  data: { username: username, password: password, token: token_value }
})
```

When I run:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$token = $_POST['token'];
$postdata = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'token' => $token);
print_r($post_data);
print_r($_SERVER);
```

I get:

```
Array (
    [username] => 
    [password] => 
    [token] => 
)
Array(
[REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
[REDIRECT_STATUS] => 404
[HTTP_HOST] => [omitted]
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
[CONTENT_LENGTH] => 71
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
[HTTP_ORIGIN] => [omitted]
[HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH] => XMLHttpRequest
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
[CONTENT_TYPE] => application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
[HTTP_REFERER] => [omitted]/auth
[HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
[HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
[PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
[SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at [omitted] Port 80</address>

[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
[SERVER_NAME] => [omitted]
[SERVER_ADDR] => [omitted]
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[REMOTE_ADDR] => [omitted]
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => [omitted]
[REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
[CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
[CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => [omitted]
[SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@localhost
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => [omitted]/public_html/index.php
[REMOTE_PORT] => 60135
[REDIRECT_URL] => /auth/login
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[REQUEST_URI] => /auth/login
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
[PHP_SELF] => /index.php
[REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1447625662.493
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1447625662
)
```

I know the above block of code works because I've tried it on a static "test.php" file and it outputs the username/password/method information submitted by this ajax request.

I really feel like the problem lies within my .htaccess file because when I force a 200 OK header it still considers it a 404 or something? I'm not sure but its scrubbing the $_POST. This issue isn't related to my php.ini or apache2.conf, since I've tested that out already and I'm able to receive post data, just not to the ErrorDocument 404 /index.php that I've been sending it to. This is what I've been using to prevent a 404 page when parsing the URL to send to the controller.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I assume mod_rewrite is active. There must be more in your `.htaccess` file. You don't have any redirects in there, only one rewrite. You also have a dangling `RewriteCond` at the end.

Comment: @OlafDietsche actually I went back and checked if I had mod_rewrite active after you posted this and it turned out to be the correct answer. You should def consider posting it as a main answer and I'll mark i as the correct one. I'm sure more people than I are having this problem.

Comment: I'm glad my comment helped. You are [allowed and encouraged to answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having the same problem I did, and nothing else seems to work, it could be that the apache module rewrite "mod_rewrite" is not active.

Run the command: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
and restart your apache server: `sudo service apache2 restart`